# Bottom Navigation Behaviour with fragments and Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack-navigation

I have an activity, `Dashboard Activity`, which has a fragment and a bottom navigation menu which is setup like this in `DashboardActivity.kt`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)
val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

The bottom nav has 3 items: `@+id/navigation_scoreboard`, `@+id/navigation_dashboard` and `@+id/navigation_gamesettings`

Within my `@+id/navigation_dashboard` bottom nav menu item - the user can enter some data in an input field and press a button on which I make an API call and navigate to the result screen, `@+id/slipup_result_fragment`, on API call success using navigation + live data observers.

**Now the problem is:** When I navigate away from the result screen, `@+id/slipup_result_fragment`,  say by going to another item in the bottom nav menu and then come press the menu item for `@+id/navigation_dashboard`, I again land at the result screen, rather than the original fragment - `@+id/navigation_dashboard` and have cannot seem to find a way to go back to the original fragment.

What am I doing wrong here?

Update: The nav graph for the fragment in the `Dashboard Activity` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_scoreboard">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_scoreboard"
        android:name="com.ezchange.mvp.ui.scoreboard.ScoreboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_scoreboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_scoreboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.ezchange.mvp.ui.slipup.SlipUpFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_slipup"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_slipup" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_dashboard_to_slipUpResultFragment"
            app:destination="@id/slipup_result_fragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_dashboard"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_gamesettings"
        android:name="com.ezchange.mvp.ui.gamesettings.GameSettingsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_game_settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game_settings" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/slipup_result_fragment"
        android:name="com.ezchange.mvp.ui.slipup.SlipUpResultFragment"
        android:label="fragment_slip_up_result"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_slip_up_result" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_slipUpResultFragment_to_navigation_scoreboard"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_scoreboard" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Update#2: The bottom menu XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_scoreboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_scoreboard" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_slipup" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_gamesettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_game_settings" />

</menu>
```

Comment: could you post the xml of nav graph ?

Comment: @NikhilSharma added

Comment: there was some error destination id, I corrected them in code now, you can check the answer.

Comment: Post also the menu of bottomNav

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti added

Answer (score 0):

When you are navigating with `action_navigation_dashboard_to_slipUpResultFragment` nav controller have info a follows -

SlipUpFragment -- > SlipUpResultFragment

on upon navigating up it will take you to SlipUpFragment without any issue.

Once you navigate to `navigation_gamesettings` nav should have info as follows  -

SlipUpFragment -- > SlipUpResultFragment -- > GameSettingsFragment

but there is no such `action_slipUpResultFragment_to_navigation_gamesettings` that's why when you navigate nav controller would be lost.

So there must be action from SlipUpResultFragment as follows -

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/slipup_result_fragment"
    android:label="fragment_slip_up_result"
    android:name="com.ezchange.mvp.ui.slipup.SlipUpResultFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_slip_up_result">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_slipUpResultFragment_to_navigation_gamesettings"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_gamesettings"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_slipUpResultFragment_to_navigation_scoreboard"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_scoreboard"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
</fragment>
```

adding `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` and `app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_dashboard"` to make sure upon navigating up, it will take you to **SlipUpFragment** not to **SlipUpResultFragment** again.

**Edit 1**

Using Following NavGraph is giving desired result - [PSR of result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dg8VIz6J8JzA-KOp0SqQSy5LV54wkPG1/view?usp=sharing)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.bottomnavigationtest.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.bottomnavigationtest.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_dashboard_to_detailsFagment"
            app:destination="@id/detailsFagment" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="com.example.bottomnavigationtest.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailsFagment"
        android:name="com.example.bottomnavigationtest.ui.dashboard.details.DetailsFagment"
        android:label="fragment_details_fagment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_details_fagment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_detailsFagment_to_navigation_home"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_home" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Happy Coding !

Comment: I think there's a confusion - I don't want to go from `@+id/navigation_dashboard'` to `@+id/navigation_gamesettings` - What's happening is when I tap the bottom nav item for the dashboard, it takes me to `@+id/slipup_result_fragment` rather than `@+id/navigation_dashboard`. Basically - once I go to the `@+id/slipup_result_fragment` then there's no way to go to the `@+id/navigation_dashboard` via the bottom nav menu

Comment: please check the my repro [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dg8VIz6J8JzA-KOp0SqQSy5LV54wkPG1/view?usp=sharing), I have edited my answer as well.

Comment: if you are still facing issue then, please post the navigation code as well.